# PHP hierarchical array - Parents and childs From single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, parent-child

It's a relationship between parents and childs.
Example: Root parent a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24-02f6e3696dde has the child temp which have the child audio.raw.

I tried recursive function, just got a mess. It's a brainer.

```
array(1 => "a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24/temp/"
      2 => "a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24/temp/audio.raw"
      3 => "a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24/temp/sub_temp/"
      4 => "a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24/temp/sub_temp/audio2.raw" )
```

Result i want is.

```
array( 'a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24' =>
                array(
                        'temp' => array(
                               '0'=>'audio.raw',
                                'sub_temp' => array('0'=>'audio2.raw')
                        )
            )
        )
```

Comment: and what to do in the case `5 => "a-98f8dc00-5a5c-0137-da24/sub_temp/0/audio2.raw"` ?

Comment: Please post your coding attempt and the specific problem you're having.  Otherwise, we assume you're just trying to get someone to give you the answer to your homework.